# Print File without print dialog box

Tags: c#

I need your help to print my locally saved file without using print dialog box , i tried out many cases but failed to do so. one case is like;

```
var pr = new PrintDocument();
pr.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
pr.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
pr.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "E:\\File.docx";
pr.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = fileName.ToString();
pr.Print();
pr.Dispose();
```

Comment: presumably, the problem is that a print dialog is displayed? As an aside, if `PrintDocment` implements `IDisposable` use a `using` block.

Comment: Why are you asigning the fileName to the PrinterName?

Comment: @Jodrell , can you show me the code to implement such approach

Comment: @jamie agree, i just wanna to assign any name , but the main property is "PrintFileName"

Comment: What if you remove the `pr.Dispose();`?

Answer (score 1):

This will start `Microsoft Word` and print the `test.rtf` while suppressing the `Print dialog box`. However, the path must be fully specified.

```
var settings = new PrinterSettings();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\WINWORD.EXE";
startInfo.Arguments = @"test.rtf /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit";
var p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```